# Unix: Prevent delete on a user file from a user

Tags: file, unix

[UNIX] Assume that there exists a user X (i.e. not a superuser), which belongs to a group G. This user X creates a file F in a directory, with permissions "rw-rw----".
Is there a way to prevent delete on this file from any user (except superusers), with a command issued by user X?
I found "chattr +a", but it can only be issued by superuser.

In other words, I am user X, member of group G, I own a file which must have permissions "rw-rw----". I want to prevent this file from deletion by myself and any other user of group G.

Comment: Well, write access can allow overwriting the file with garbage.

Comment: Write access is necessary because the file can be modified (like in "append" mode, not in "overwrite" mode)

Comment: Once a user has write access he can ovewrite whatever he pleases.

Comment: That is not true, indeed for example if I am root and I create a file F wherever I want with permissions "rw-------", and I execute "chattr +i F", the command "rm F" gives "permission denied" even though I have write permission.
Of course I can remove the protection with "chattr -i F" and then delete the file.

Point is, I don't want to prevent delete in general, but from an "accident".

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to provide a script owned by root and with setuid flag on. That script would only run egainst files located in a particular directory so as to avoid a confused deputy attack.

An other possibility that I did not explore is to use ACL's which provide more granularity than the standard rwx.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to solve the wrong problem ("I want to protect against accidental deletion of my own files").

The usual countermeasure is backups and/or archival. For single files I simply check them in with RCS, i.e. `ci -l precious.txt` each time I modify them. Note that this solution also solves the problem of accidental *modifications*, since you can checkout any earlier version with ease.

See the manuals for rcsintro(1), ci(1), co(1) and rcsdiff(1).

Comment: This is an excellent point. If you are worried about accidents, the solution is _backups_ (or revision control). This is a long tested solution to the problem.